# How to use a global variable in modules too?

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a python flask app (an api server).
I want to get browser's language value from the request, and be able to transparently (without passing it explicitly) use it in all the modules I use.

Now I do something like:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from modules.recipe import Recipe   

app = Flask(__name__)

recipe = Recipe()

global language

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
  language = request.headers.get('language')
  args = request.args.to_dict()
  q = args["q"]
  results = recipe.search(q)
  return jsonify(results)
```

I would like to be able to use the `language` variable value in modules.recipe module, too.
But, when I try to acces it in any module, I get error "`name 'language' is not defined`".

Which is the correct approach, if one exists?

One more question: is it possible to someway call the `request.headers.get('language')` stuff once for every routes, but inside the `request context` ?

Answer (score 1):

Flask provides a g object which is unique for each request. You can store the language there and access it throughout your request's context from flask.

```
import Flask, request, jsonify, g
from modules.recipe import Recipe

app = Flask(__name__)
recipe = Recipe()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.language = request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'default_language')

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
    args = request.args.to_dict()
    q = args["q"]
    results = recipe.search(q, g.language)  # Pass language as a parameter
    return jsonify(results)

# In modules/recipe.py
class Recipe:
    def search(self, query, language):
        # use language here
        pass
```

Regarding your second question: to call `request.headers.get('language')` once for every route, you can use the @app.before_request decorator. This decorator allows you to define a function that runs before each request, and you can use it to set a global or context-specific variable.

Example using @app.before_request:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    g.language = request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'default_language'
)
```